# Did Keller Dover die?

Tags: prisoners

At the end of *Prisoners* Keller Dover was forced to jump into the dark pit hole below the junked car on gunpoint by Mrs Jones. He was seen finding a red whistle that fell from his daughter using a mobile torch. Was he able to make a phonecall to his wife or Detective Loki or did the last scene mean to give us all hope?

I think it was at least 2 days since Keller had been confined to the hole. It'd be difficult to find him alive. Was Keller rescued?